# My Desktop wont turn on anymore

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios

Hey It just happen to me and searching for answers.

I have a 5yr old desktop computer with motherboard Gigabyte GA-H61M-DS2 with os win764 never been reformatted until this past week when i wasnt able to remove my flash drive(with partedmagic boot installed) it run and i just do the ctl+alt+del to choose proper boot and the problem arised it just turned off

when i press now the power button, it just blink once the cpu fan attempts to rotate but will stop as soon as the power button led also stops and it will not boot.

please help

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this situation once and what I did was power drain and reseating the RAM. After that it worked for me. I suggest your to try these 2 simple steps.
To perform the power drain, disconnect all the devices from the CPU. Press and hold the power button for 10-15 seconds to drain the excess charge on the motherboard. Once done connect the wires and power on your desktop.